# Yii default ajax search redirection

Tags: yii

If only single result found from the default Yii ajax search, I want to redirect to it's view action. How can I trigger the redirection?. (This is similar to Google's "I'm feeling lucky" Option)

Comment: a few more details will help in answering, like what have you tried? what default search are you talking about?

Comment: You will have to write a custom javascript function that will update the CGridView with the result from the server, and if the number of results equals to 1, redirets the page. This is pretty easy, if besides the rendered HTML you also send a result count and/or URL to redirect to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself,

I endup with javascript hack coz I couldn't find a proper way to do it.

In my CGridView I used **afterAjaxUpdate**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'summaryCssClass'=>'summary fr',
    'id'=>'order-grid',
    'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'function(id, options){ if($("#order-grid tbody tr").length == 1 && $("#order-grid tbody tr:first td").length > 1) {window.location = $("#order-grid tbody tr td:first a").attr("href");}}',
    'columns' => array()
));
```

Hope this helps to someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function actionAdmin() {
        $this->pageTitle = Yii::app()->name . ' - Customer Support';

        $model = new residence('customer');

        $model->unsetAttributes();

        if (isset($_GET['residence']))
            $model->attributes = $_GET['residence'];
        if (!Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest && isset($_GET['search_field'])) {
            $raw = $model->customer()->getData();
            if (count($raw) == 1) {
                $this->redirect(array("customer/details", "id" => $raw[0]->id));
            }
        }

        $this->render('admin', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
    }
```

where $model->customer() returns the DataProvider that the grid also uses.